# Ruby on Rails Chartkick data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, chartkick

I am working on a multiple series line chart in ruby on rails.  I have passed to the chart data as such:

```
<%= line_chart @budget.transactions.group(:category).group(:date).sum(:amount) %>
```

In the developer tools I looked at the script that populates the chart and it looks like:

```
new Chartkick.LineChart("chart-2", [{"name":"debt","data":[["2017-04-19",5.43],["2017-04-20",60.0]]},
{"name":"entertainment","data":[["2017-04-19",30.0]]},
{"name":"food","data":[["2017-04-20",15.0],["2017-04-21",20.0]]},
{"name":"housing","data":[["2017-04-02",17.33],["2017-04-10",20.0],["2017-05-01",522.0]]},
{"name":"transportation","data":[["2017-04-20",50.0]]},
{"name":"utilities","data":[["2017-04-19",35.0],["2017-04-21",20.0],["2017-04-27",77.34]]}], {});
```

To me the format for the data being passed to the chart seems correct, but the output... not so much.  Also I was thinking using the Ruby Date class, rather than DateTime was causing a problem but I'm not sure.  Any help appreciated. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnIg8.png)

Comment: If be honest I don't understand your question :(

Comment: If you check the image, none of the lines are connected and the data passed in seems correct to me.  I'm looking to see if I grouped the data wrong or if I'm using the wrong types etc.